# Relay Access Denied (State 13) Postfix + Dovecot + Mysql

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot

So we have been scratching our heads for quite some time over this relay issue that has presented itself since we re-built our mail-server after a failed Webmin update. We are running Debian Karmic with postfix 2.6.5 and Dovecot 1.1.11, sourcing from a Mysql database and authenticating with SASL2 and PAM. Here are the symptoms of our problem:

1) When users are on our local network they can send and receive 100% perfectly fine.

2) When users are off our local network and try to send to domains not of this mail server (ie. gmail) they get the "Relay Access Denied" error. However users can send to domains of this mail server when off the local network fine.

3) We host several virtual domains on this mailserver, the primary domain being airnet.ca. The rest of our virtual domains (ex. jeptha.ca) cannot receive email from domains not hosted by this mailserver (ie. gmail and such cannot send to them). They receive bounce backs of "Relay Access Denied (State 13)". This is regardless of whether they are on our local network or not, which is why it is so urgent for us to get this solved.

Here is our main.cf from postfix:

```
myhostname = mail.airnet.ca
mydomain = airnet.ca
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated        
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/alias.cf hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = mail.airnet.ca, airnet.ca, localhost.$mydomain
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
local_recipient_maps = $alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps proxy:unix:passwd.byname
home_mailbox = /var/virtual/
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
mailbox_transport = maildrop
smtpd_helo_required = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_etrn_restrictions = reject
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
show_user_unknown_table_name = no
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps
$virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains
$relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps
$recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks
$virtual_mailbox_limit_maps $virtual_uid_maps $virtual_gid_maps
virtual_alias_domains =
message_size_limit = 20971520
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/vdomain.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/vmailbox.cf
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/alias.cf hash:/etc/mailman/aliases
virtual_uid_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/vuid.cf
virtual_gid_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/vgid.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /
virtual_mailbox_limit = 209715200
virtual_mailbox_extended = yes
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/vmlimit.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit_inbox = no
virtual_overquote_bounce = yes
virtual_minimum_uid = 1
maximal_queue_lifetime = 1d
bounce_queue_lifetime = 4h
delay_warning_time = 1h
append_dot_mydomain = no
qmgr_message_active_limit = 500
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtp_bind_address = 142.46.193.6
relay_domains = $mydestination
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0, 142.46.193.0/25
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

And here is the master.cf from postfix:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628      inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

spfpolicy   unix    -   n   n   -   -   spawn
    user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl
smtp-amavis unix    -   -   n   -   4   smtp
 -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
 -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
 -o disable_dns_lookups=yes

#127.0.0.1:10025    inet    n   -   n   -   -   smtpd

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=dovecot:21pever1lcha0s argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient
```

Here is Dovecot.conf

```
protocols = imap imaps pop3 pop3s

disable_plaintext_auth = no

log_path = /etc/dovecot/logs/err
info_log_path = /etc/dovecot/logs/info
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ".
syslog_facility = mail

ssl_listen = 142.46.193.6
ssl_disable = no
ssl_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
ssl_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/virtual/%d/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_debug = yes


protocol imap {
  login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
     mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/rawlog /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
     mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/gdbhelper /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
  mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
  imap_max_line_length = 65536
  mail_max_userip_connections = 20
  mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/imap
  login_greeting_capability = yes
}

protocol pop3 {
  login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
  mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
  pop3_enable_last = no
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
  mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/pop3
}

protocol managesieve {
  sieve=~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_storage=~/sieve
}

mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lda

auth_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-auth
auth_process_size = 256
auth_cache_ttl = 3600
auth_cache_negative_ttl = 3600
auth_username_chars = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890.-_@
auth_verbose = yes
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_worker_max_count = 60
auth_failure_delay = 2
auth default {
  mechanisms = plain login
    passdb sql {
      args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
    }
    userdb sql {
      args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
    }
      socket listen {
        client {
          path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
          mode = 0660
          user = postfix
          group = postfix
        }
        master {
          path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
          mode = 0600
      }
    }
 }
```

Please, if you require anything do not hesistate, I will post it ASAP. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Pierre

Comment: You may want to add `smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destinations`
 and `smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination`
 have a look at this http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html

Comment: I put those 2 lines in and got the following in mail.log as well as not being able to send email in any of the above mentioned circumstances

Dec 4 19:28:10 mail postfix/smtpd[26279]: fatal: parameter "smtpd_recipient_restrictions": specify at least one working instance of: check_relay_domains, reject_unauth_destination, reject, defer or defer_if_permit

I removed the smtp_recipient_restrictions line and can now send again.I have read that link already and followed the advice given on it.At this moment we are not too fixated on restricting sending rcpts but more so getting sending working

Comment: If I had to take a wild stab at it, I'd guess that Postfix and/or Dovecot can't read those MySQL databases, since mail flow is working fine for `$mynetworks` and local delivery, but not virtual delivery.

Comment: I am the second tech at Airnet.
It appears with the crash we lost our courier and squirrelmail.
We have replaced courier with dovecot and squirrelmail with roundcube
Round cube works and local domain airnet.ca works.
Other virtual domains are not been recognized by postfix/dovecot EDIT - Also see a lot of proxy stuff which I think may belong to imapproxy which also crashed with the original carsh and never came back We are looking for someone to go over our main.cf and master.cf to see what mistakes are there, as we have been looking at this for a bit and feel a fresh pair of eyes will find ou

Comment: There's nothing wrong with postfix, but I'm guessing you may have not restored your mysql databases properly. Open one of those files, the run the query inside, using the username and password contained inside. Users work from inside because they match `$mynetworks`, but virtual domains may have been restored badly (as may have other tables).

Answer (score 1):

Please create an A record for mail.airnet.ca.

Also make sure that you use "Server requires authentication" in your email client and that your server is not blacklisted: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx